# calling ajax function that is outside document.ready

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to populate a Google Map. Here's some of my code. Why won't this ajax request work? It works fine when I stick it all in the document.ready() as an anonymous function, but I want to reuse this code, so I need to be able to call it.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        center: {lat: 49.105, lng: -97.568},
        zoom: 4
      });

getTornadoes("test", "test", "yes");            

});

// Get the tornado JSON file
    function getTornadoes (test, test2, test3) {//These are not my real parameters

        $.getJSON('water_pollutants.php', function(data){

            $.each(data.features, function(index, feature){

                var longitude = feature.properties.LONGITUDE;
                var latitude = feature.properties.LATITUDE;
                ...
```

I get the error InvalidValueError: setMap: not an instance of Map; and not an instance of StreetViewPanorama. However, I don't think this is an issue with Google Maps. I've had similar issues in the past when trying to refer to ajax functions that are declared outside document.ready().

Comment: Place what outside the ready function? If it's the Google maps code, it uses `getElementById` which requires that the element is present before it can get it ?

Comment: getElementById like div id exist?

Comment: @adeneo my ajax call is outside document.ready(). The google map works perfectly fine when I use it as an anonymous function within document.ready(), but I don't want to use it anonymously.

Comment: @HenriqueYahCenteno Yes, it does. The google map works perfectly fine when I use it as an anonymous function within document.ready(), but I don't want to use it anonymously.

Comment: If you move it outside the ready function, the `#map` element can't be found. If you want to move it, wrap it in a function you can call.

Comment: @adeneo Thanks. I just stuck my whole map statement inside the getTornadoes() function. I knew it was something silly...

Answer (score 0):

I use google maps api also, here is one recommendation:

change

```
$(document).ready(function(){

      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        center: {lat: 49.105, lng: -97.568},
        zoom: 4
      });
```

to:

```
var map;

$(document).ready(function(){

      map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        center: {lat: 49.105, lng: -97.568},
        zoom: 4
      });
```

Comment: Thanks. This works, but I actually prefer Adeneo's method in the comments. That way, I'm avoiding global scope. I appreicate you showing me in code, though. I just stuck my entire map statement inside the getTornadoes function.